# Replacing nginx default pages with custom pages using docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to use custom made HTML pages instead of default error pages of nginx such as 400 or 404. I added below lines based on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial in my `DockerFile` but when I test it, it again shows the default nginx error page. Can you help me with it?

```
FROM nginx:1.19.6
COPY custom_400.html /usr/share/nginx/html/custom_400.html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

and here is the `default` file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}

    error_page 400 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Moreover, editing your question to add more details has very little chances to make it [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here as it is not related to programming but to web server configuration. It should be moved to https://superuser.com.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the info but it seems I can not create a new post in there and need to wait 40 minutes or so. If it is not the right place to ask this question, can you please move it there?

Comment: just be patient and move it there when time comes.

Comment: How do you build your docker image? When I try, using your Dockerfile, it fails when it tries to delete the default configuration because there's no such file in the nginx:1.19.6 image.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be that you sometimes use 400 and sometimes use 404. When they don't match, it doesn't work. But there are also other issues, like you putting your Nginx configuration file into the `sites-enabled` directory, which doesn't exist in a default nginx configuration.

Here's how you can get it to work.

First, rename custom_400.html to custom_404.html

Change your `default` file to this (just change all 400 occurrences to 404)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
}
```

Change your Dockerfile to this (place your config file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf)

```
FROM nginx:1.19.6
COPY custom_404.html /usr/share/nginx/html/custom_404.html
COPY default /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Build the image and run it

```
docker build -t testimage .
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:80 testimage
```

Try to get a non-existing page using curl or a browser

```
curl http://localhost:8080/xyzzy
```

You should get your custom page back.